Remembering the setting to use and extend the external display
I have a laptop and an external display connected to it via USB-C. I extended these displays (the external display and the laptop display) and set my external display as the main one. So far so good.
My laptop is connected to the charger and there is no power-related action on closing the lid. When I close the lid, everything is displayed on the external display. Great so far.
However, when I open the lid again, the laptop becomes the only display. I have to both extend the monitors again and move windows to the external monitor. How can I make Windows remember that the multi-monitor setup should be used?
